# Generate the use cases from user stories

Tags: java, uml, papyrus

i am a student and i must do a project.I want to generate Use cases- and class diagrams from user stories. Is there any suggestion to do that.
i have already used the papyrus plugin but it can not help me .It does just reversing java code to class diagrams

Comment: Try Visual Paradigm. It lets you convert UML into basic class outlines https://www.visual-paradigm.com/features/

Comment: you have not recognize my problem .I want to convert  User stories to Class Diagrams and Use cases

Comment: What you want is not possible. Take, for example, the following user story: "As a student, I want to subscribe for a course, in order to find a decent job in the future." No tooling will ever be able to generate a proper class diagram or a proper use case from this single sentence.

Comment: I don't get it. You are asking for UC from user stories and in the details you ask to RE Java code. What?

Answer (score 2):

Converting a user story into a use case is not something that a tool will help you do, it is, however, something that a tool, like Papyrus and many others, will help you represent and that provides you with graphical elements to extract and visualize structure and behaviour from your analysis of the problem. Tools are, well, tools, not a panacea to your problems as they will not think for you.

Simply stated...

A user story is typically "As a *user*, I want to *do something* so I can *have a result/benefit*.

A use case (which is really textual, BTW) is typically: precondition, actions and responses, post-conditions, alternate scenarios, etc.

In UML, the *user* becomes an actor and the __do something_ becomes your use case. The *result/benefit* represents the goal/success factor for your use case (and, in some way, post-conditions). Pre- and post-conditions are constraints. actions and responses can be expressed as interactions (sequence diagrams), activities, and state machines.

From this point on, you have to start thinking about how you will implement this and there are many techniques that can do this (functional decomposition, behavioural decomposition, mapping to patterns such as MVC, etc.). Which one you use will depend on your background, domain or expertise, preference, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my answer after reading your comments.

Take a look at [Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com/products/ea/). Does not do that kind of "magic", but still has many tools and diagrams that allow to capture most steps from the software analysis/design process. You can download a free trial.